# Neural network written from scratch learns much slower than PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, backpropagation

I wrote a program from scratch using numpy for the feeding forward and backprogation of a network. I tested it against a program written using PyTorch with the same architecture and the network from scartch is around 200 times slower. What reasons do you think could cause this, and how much slower or faster would you expect a well written program from scratch to be compared to using PyTorch.

The architecture of the network is a 2 stacked GRU followed by a MLP; the optimiser is Adam; and mini-batch learning is implemented in both.

Comment: Slower in terms of number of epochs needed, or in execution time?

Comment: @jonnor in terms of execution time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Software like PyTorch, or TensorFlow, are popular because they can use GPUs, what gives them advantage, most of it is implemented in C++, that is generally faster than Python, there is also a lot of optimizations made in the code that make it efficient and robust, it is also well tested and documented, and easy to use. PyTorch has over 1500 contributors and the code was developed for several years and used in production environment in many companies, including Facebook, so you would not usually expect to achieve similar results when coding it from scratch by yourself.

If need to implement it from scratch and need to be fast, I'd start with using a programming language that is faster than Python (it is rather slow), e.g. C/C++, or Julia.

Comment: The program will be constantly used so it is quite important to make it fairly fast. I needed to implement it from scratch because it will be used in a system without any libraries for neural networks. How much would you expect using GPUs to speed up execution time?

Comment: @EFresher depends on many details, but from none to a lot.

Comment: Could I provide you some more details for you to better evaluate the situation?

Comment: @EFresher if as you say, in the system where this would be running there is no external libs available, than you seem to be needing to use Numpy, so probably not worth considering PyTorch? On another hand, if you need different packages, than maybe you can pack it into a Docker container?

Comment: PyTorch was never a consideration, it was just for me to compare my numpy program from scratch with a highly optimised one. I have also just found out that in my PyTorch program only CPU was used, so it seems that the slow speed is caused by poorly written code or maths. I'm hoping to get some inspirations on how I can improve the efficiency.